# Как получить список средних значений?

Tags: python

Есть два списка `[0,1,1,2,3,4]` и `[5,5,7,4,9,10]`. Как можно получить список средних значений?

Например `[2,5;3;4;3...7]`

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так:

```
list1 = [0,1,1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,5,7,4,9,10]

list(map(lambda x: (x[0] + x[1]) / 2, zip(list1, list2))) # [2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: Я бы написал `sum(x) / len(x)`. Более универсально.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, да, вы правы `list(map(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x), zip(list1, list2)))`

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но х вроде как не итерабл, а просто инт

Comment: zip возвращает iterable с кортежами

Comment: @PavelDurmanov, `zip` ведь делает кортеж.

Comment: А, точно, я слепой) Тогда все верно